# Applying UPDATE query to query table using Access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to update a query table which contains all null values replace with 'n/a' string. but it is throwing an error "“Operation must use an updateable query” . My query table has a field EID which contains null value like.

```
 EID  Value
       78.00
```

Which contain only one row,

My query

```
Update EID_NULL Set [EID] ='n/a' Where [EID] Is Null;
```

can we able to apply update query to a query table?

Comment: You wouldn't use an update query for anything other than changing the values in your database.  Is your QT in Excel?

Comment: no its in access. but if we need to update query table is there any way to do this?

Comment: You never "update" a query.  Just change the select to use a case statement on the EID field.

Comment: @ jbarker2160 Could you please specify a query, thanks.

Comment: `SO` is not for that.  If you share your original SELECT statement I can suggest some edits.